# How to change UIButton to a different Uibutton after clicking segmented controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The image below is a picture of a view with two uibarbuttons  and a segmented control. The salesforce button when reached redirects the user to a website.How can I change the salesforce button to a different button when the third index of the segment control is reached ? This second button is meant to display a new view controller.

[image]

Comment: What does change to a different button _mean_?  Change the title? Change what it does when tapped? Both?

Comment: @matt Sorry for not being specific I meant change to a different buttton that shows edit. This edit button is meant show a new view controller when pressed

Comment: This question needs more detail. How are you creating your view (storyboard, code)?

Comment: Again, that doesn't necessitate a different _button_. All you've described so far is that you want to change the _title_.

Comment: @burnsi built in story board but I want create the second button programmatically that does a different function

Comment: Well. Then my solution should apply. If not please add enough code so we can see what happens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to change the appearance and the button behaviour instead of changing the button itself.

Sadly you didn´t provide any context if this view is from a storyboard or created by code. In my answer I´m assuming it´s from storyboard.

- Create an outlet for you button:

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
  ```
- From your `UISegmentedControl` in storyboard create an `IBAction` in your viewcontroller. That action should look something like this.

  ```
  @IBAction func segmentedControl(sender: AnyObject) {

      configureButton(for: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

  }
  ```
- Then create that function:

  ```
   func configureButton(for index: Int){
        switch index{
            case 1:
              // assign the function that should execute as soon as the button gets pressed
              myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(functionName), for: .touchUpInside)
              // change title
              myButton.setTitle("title for button", for: .normal)
            // add all other cases
            // add default
            default:
              print("not implemented")
        }


    }
  ```

If no `IBAction` is defined for your `myButton` you would need to call the `configureButton` function from your `viewDidLoad` function.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get the index of the selected segment using, `.selectedSegemtIndex` property.Then, check the condition stating that, if the index is equals your target segment index, define statements to change the title, background color, or even the action of the button if required.